# How to run batch command with spaces from python?

Tags: python, batch-file, scripting

I am trying to run

```
compile_command = r'"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/MSBuild/15.0/Bin\MSBuild.exe" "input/Applications/EPMD-Software/IpProtector/IpProtector.sln" /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration = Release /p:Platform = x64'
os.system(compile_command)
```

and getting

> 'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

How do I get windows to understand the string with spaces? Can't rename "program files" unfortunately...

Thanks

Comment: `c = r'''"C:\foo bar\New text document.bat"'''` works but I got the same error when using a single single quote for the raw string. Try triple single quotes instead of a single single quote for the raw string.

Comment: `r'"C:\foo bar\New text document.bat" a/b/d  bah'` works and `r'''"C:\foo bar\New text document.bat" 'a/b/d'  bah'''` works. Try removing the quotes from `"input/Applications/EPMD-Software/IpProtector/IpProtector.sln"` or triple quotes around the whole string and single quotes around `input/Applications/EPMD-Software/IpProtector/IpProtector.sln`

Comment: When doing both it seems to work. Thanks! Any explanation for this?

Comment: ..There are a number of hits with a search for `python windows execute string spaces` - probably a duplicate somewhere and maybe a `why`.

Comment: Now it complains about getting 2 projects as imput to the compiler. probably something to do with the options... is there a right way of doing this?

Comment: Sorry, don't know anything about `MSBuild.exe`. sounds like a different question.

Comment: running ' "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/MSBuild/15.0/Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\code\EPMD\Installer\input\Applications\EPMD-Software\IpProtector\IpProtector.sln" "/t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform = x64" ' in cmd gives desired output. running `compile_command = r'''"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/MSBuild/15.0/Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\code\EPMD\Installer\input\Applications\EPMD-Software\IpProtector\IpProtector.sln" "/t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform = x64"'''
    os.system(compile_command)` gives original prob

Comment: the duplicate question gives a strange permissions error

Comment: Works for me....

Comment: from the duplicate's lower rated answers: `compile_command = r'""C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/MSBuild/15.0/Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\code\EPMD\Installer\input\Applications\EPMD-Software\IpProtector\IpProtector.sln" "/t:Rebuild" "/p:Configuration=Release" "/p:Platform=x64""'` double quotes. I hate batch.